# iPhone app adding new entry line

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am new to ios app development I have been working on a small app that you may see below I have attached my code. What I am looking to do is add a button at the bottom of the app to allow the user to add another line each time the button is tapped another line would include another 3 columns, swell as adding a new line each time the button is tapped I would like the total(c & d in this case) to follow the same pattern as in the code. Multiply the weight(textField2 & textField3) by the number of(x): and add to previous total(c & d). Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Example:**

Number of:    10

Name   Weight   Total

a       10       100

b       5       150

** I now want to give the user the option to add another 3 columns and continue on**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (IBAction)calculate {
    float x = ([textField1.text floatValue]);

float c = x*([textField2.text floatValue]);
float d = c+x*([textField3.text floatValue]);

label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", c];
label2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", d];}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you add more clarity to your question? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of dynamic list-based drawing you're looking to do is better suited to UITableViews than just putting labels into a view.  If you keep adding the labels to the view, you will eventually run out of space and unless the view you're using is a UIScrollView, you won't be able to scroll down to see your additional results.

An introduction to UITableViews is a bit beyond the scope of something I can type in here, I think, but you can find a lot of good tutorials online - here's one with sample code from GitHub: https://github.com/vladexologija/UITableView-introduction

After you've gained a bit of familiarity with table views, I would, in this case:
The additional rows you're adding are just cells in the table view, and the button you're looking to add at the end, should be in a UIView and assigned as the table's footer view.